# Export multiple pivot charts to new word document

Tags: vba, excel, charts, ms-word

I'm wondering if anyone can help me out on what I'm sure is an incredibly easy procedure, but I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing with VBA.

I'm creating an automated Excel document to produce a series of pivot charts and while this part works fine, I'm now looking to add a macro to then export all these charts to a new word document.

I've found some code online that seems to work in some aspects, but it's not quite what I'm looking for.
Please see below for the code:

```
`Sub ChartToWord()

Dim wdApp As Word.Application

'Copy Chart
Sheets("SHEET NAME HERE").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy

On Error Resume Next
'Try to establish link to open instance of Word
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

'If this fails, open Word
If wdApp Is Nothing Then
Set wdApp = GetObject("", "Word.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0

With wdApp
'Add new document
.Documents.Add
'Make Word visible
.Visible = True
End With
With wdApp.Selection

'Go to end of document and insert paragraph
.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
.PageSetup.PaperSize = wdPaperA3
.PageSetup.MirrorMargins = wdNarrow
.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
.Font.Bold = wdToggle
.Font.Size = 18
.TypeText Text:="Title of Page to go here"
.Font.Size = 10
.TypeParagraph
'Paste Chart
.PasteSpecial , Link:=False, DataType:=14, _
DisplayAsIcon:=False
End With
With Selection
.Width = 500
.Height = 500
End With

'Release object variable
Set wdApp = Nothing
End Sub`
```

So some of the issues I'm having with this script
- The word document doesn't appear to change orientation as it should
- I also need the document to be sized A3 and with narrow margins, to allow maximum use of space
- I would need to add in another several charts to this same document, is there any way I could do that within this one code, separated by one page?
- The current code doesn't change the size of the chart in the Word document, but instead in my Excel file?
- The code currently pastes as a picture, rather than a pivot table. Is there anyway to change this?

I'm really sorry if I'm asking a lot here, I just have no clue about VBA whatsoever and I'm a bit over my head!

Answer (score 0):

You're right, there are a lot of questions here and it's not usual to cover so much in one post on StackOverflow. Also, I'm travelling without a production machine at hand, so I probably won't be able to address everything, here, but let's see if we can at least get things moving...

1. When your code addresses more than one application you need to make sure VBA understands where it should be working. This is a problem when the applications both support the same object names. In this case, both Excel and Word use "Selection".

You can get around this by declaring objects specific to applications and instantiating, for example:

```
Dim wdSel as Word.Selection, xlSel as Excel.Selection
Set wdSel = wdApp.Selection
Set xlSel = Application.Selection
```

2. Your instantiation of the Word.Application is wrong. If `GetObject` doesn't work the first time it's probably not going to work the second time. to "open Word":  `Set wdApp = new Word.Application`
3. I'm not certain that the list of properties you cite in the block With `wdApp.Selection` belong to the `Selection` object. Correctly, the first few of them belong to the Document.PageSetup object. You should do some research on each property in the Help / documentation and make sure you're calling them correctly. In order to work with the Document object, declare a variable and instantiate it when creating the new document:

   Dim wdDoc as Word.Document = wdApp.Documents.Add()

And rather than using Selection to work with text, use the Range object. Again, you need to distinguish this from an Excel Range so:

```
Dim wdRng as Word.Range
Set wdRng = wdSel.Range
wdRng.Text = "Title text here"
wdRng.Font.Name = "Arial"
'and so on
```

When you're done manipulating a part of the Range and want to put in something new, you have to move the focus to the edge (start of end) of the Range. Otherwise you'll end up replacing the original content. Think of it like pressing the left or right arrow key to collapse a selection in the UI: `wdRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd`

4. When you paste the chart from Excel the big question is going to be: is it selected? If yes, then you can use wdSel and the re-sizing will work.

If not, then you need to determine whether it was pasted as a Shape or an InlineShape. And that depends on how the user has configured his Word installation. I can't remember, but I think PasteSpecial may have a parameter that allows you to set whether inline...